# What is the interpolation method of python matplotlib contourf

Tags: python, matplotlib, interpolation, contourf

Maybe it's right before my eyes, but I fail to see it...

Does anyone know what is the default interpolation method of python matplotlib contourf? Where can I find relative documentation?

A secondary question is "can I change that method, and how?".

Thank you in advance.

Sakis

Answer (score 1):

I think they use something like a "marching squares" algorithm, similar to this implementation here in `scikit-image`:

To change the method you could simply evaluate the contour-arrays and then plot them as lines or filled polygons... for example:

https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_contours.html